# How to shorten function checking multiple booleans

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this challenge with my code where I want to change this:

```
   function validateLoanAmount(){

      var loan_amount = $('[name=loan_amount]');

      if(loan_amount.val() == ''){
        showError(loan_amount, 'Field can\'t be empty');
        return false;
      }

      if(loan_amount.val() <= 0){
        showError(loan_amount, 'Value can\'t equal 0 or less');
        return false;
      }
    }
```

into this:

```
function validateLoanTerm(){

  var loan_term = $('[name=loan_term]');

  isEmpty(loan_term);
  isEqualZeroOrLess(loan_term);
}

function isEmpty(element){
  if(element.val() == ''){
    showError(element, 'Field can\'t be empty');
    return false;
  }
}

function isEqualZeroOrLess(element){
  if(element.val() <= 0){
    showError(element, 'Value can\'t equal 0 or less');
    return false;
  }
}
```

I tried to put `return` in front of `isEmpty()` and `isEqualToZeroOrLess()`, but then only first function resolved. It looks like a simple function to make shorter (because I have many similar inputs to validate and I want to keep it DRY), but looks like it's more complicated than I initially thought. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need a *return* for *"else"* conditions also. None of your functions ever return `true`

Comment: You have to return true at some point within isEmpty and isEqualZeroOrLess (can you name that differently? isNotPositiveNumber? Something? )

Comment: If your code works, and you are asking others to review it, [codereview.se] may be the best place for the question. Do read their help center for what's on topic and not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the calls with `&&`:

```
function validateLoanTerm(){
    var loan_term = $('[name=loan_term]');
    return isEmpty(loan_term) && isEqualZeroOrLess(loan_term);
}
```

But for this to work, the functions need to return `true` when there's no error.

```
function isEmpty(element){
  if(element.val() == ''){
    showError(element, 'Field can\'t be empty');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function isEqualZeroOrLess(element){
  if(element.val() <= 0){
    showError(element, 'Value can\'t equal 0 or less');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm - I don't know why I didn't though of that